# Script is working in browser but not when requested by API

Tags: php, mysql, apache, api, get

I have the following script:

```
<?php
require_once("config/db.php");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO SMS
(receiver, sender, message, date, reference)
VALUES
('".$_GET['receiver']."', '".$_GET['sender']."', '".$_GET['message']."', '".$_GET['date']."', '".$_GET['reference']."')")
or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

When I open this page with a webbrowser

> import.php?receiver=316XXXXXXXX&sender=316XXXXXXXX&message=Wtf&date=1401700682&date_utc=1401693482&reference=4665583XX

the information is added to my database.

However, when an API visits (and tries to post to) the page, nothing happens at all. But, in my Apache acces log the visit is there:

```
212.61.XXX.XXX - - [02/Jun/2014:09:18:02 +0200] "GET /import.php?receiver=3164XXXXXXXX&sender=316XXXXXXXX&message=Wtf&date=1401700682&date_utc=1401693482&reference=4665583XX HTTP/1.1" 200 44 "-" "-"
```

I have no clue what is happening. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: yes the api is hitting the end point with GET, could you also check the error log and see there is something and also you are using /import.php in the api instead try to give the full path i.e. `GET http://yourdomain.com/import.php?....`

Comment: **SQL escape your parameters** as it stands if you have a `'` in `$_GET['message']` its going to break!!!

Comment: **Obligatory suggestion**, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an IP check that was performed on the page. My IP was whitelisted, the IP of the API not. Stupid mistake.

Thank for all answers and for ways to improve my code.

Answer (score 2):

So try escaping your parameters, I suspect that the message your wanting to insert contains a `'`, even know your redacting it.

```
<?php
require_once("config/db.php");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO SMS (receiver, sender, message, date, reference)
                VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['receiver'])."', 
                        '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sender'])."', 
                        '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['message'])."', 
                        '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['date'])."', 
                        '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['reference'])."')") 
            or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

But before you write any more code, you should use [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) with [prepared query's](http://j.mp/T9hLWi), here's your code ported to PDO (See how much cleaner it is, and your be SQL injection free [accidental or not]):

```
<?php 
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$dbname = "da_database";
$user = "username";
$pass = "password";

try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname, $user, $pass, array(
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
    );

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //you could mail() this
    die('<pre>'.$e->getMessage().'</pre>');
}

try{
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("
    INSERT INTO SMS (receiver, sender, message, date, reference)
                VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    $sql->bindValue(1, $_GET['receiver']);
    $sql->bindValue(2, $_GET['sender']);
    $sql->bindValue(3, $_GET['message']);
    $sql->bindValue(4, $_GET['date']);
    $sql->bindValue(5, $_GET['reference']);

    $sql->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e){
    //you could mail() this
    die('<pre>'.$e->getMessage().'</pre>');
}
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will have a look at MySQLi and PDO later. However, for now, the script is working (in my browser). When I copy the request from my Apache Access Log (as seen above) in my browser, it adds the information into the database. Also, as you can see in the log, there are no charackters like ' in the GET request.

The problem is that nothing happens when the API requests the page.

Comment: Its odd, as that is most likely the issue, are you using curl to GET the API? what does it return, if its an issue with the INSERT query then it will return the mysql_error(), also do you have any SQL restraints or set data types for the columns, e.g are they all varchar(). Also check your error.log for clues.